# Properway to pass information from one system to another in an entity component system design

Tags: entity-system, entity-component, entity-component-system

After having read some example programs (namely Pong, Snake and Pacman) I am now experiencing with ECS. I am wondering where to put the elements for a reward flow. Do you know good practices for implementing the following feature in an ECS spirit?

## Example:

Let `coins_reward` be a component carrying an amount of coins to be rewarded, `energy_gauge` be a component storing the remaining energy of an entity and `damage` be a component storing the damage inflicted to an entity.

Let say that there are enemies on the map, each enemy has an `energy_gauge`, maybe a `damage` if he has been hit and maybe a `coins_reward` if he his supposed to reward the player for killing him.

Let `propagate_damages` be the system that propagate the damages:

```
propagate_damages()
{
    collect_and_do<energy_gauge, damage>(apply_damage);
}

apply_damage(entity e, energy_gauge g, damage d)
{
    g.value -= d.value;

    if ( g.value > 0 )
        return;

    coins_reward r = get_optional_component<coins_reward>(e);

    if ( !r )
        return;

    reward_player(r);
}
```

Now how should be implemented `reward_player()`?

I though about the following designs:

1. Immediately give the reward to the player. This one seems to be out of scope for `propagate_damages`. Following the single responsibility principle I would rather have the player's state updated in another system.
2. Spawn a new entity and give him the `coins_reward` component as well as a `collectible` component. Then in a `collect_rewards` system collect the entities with these components and give them to the player. This one feels weird to me because temporary entities are created to carry information for another system. It feels more like I need a message system. Is it usual to have entities whose whole lifetime fits in a frame? On the plus side if I assign a position to this entity then I may be able to spawn visual indicators of the rewards on the map in another system.
3. Have a reference to the `collect_reward` system inside `propagate_damages` and queue the rewards here. Then process `collect_reward` later in the frame. If I pass the position here I can also spawn indicators on the map. In this case there no entities created but it does not feel like ECS.

For now I would go with number 2 but the entity-as-message part does not feel good. Is it how you would do it? Experienced programmers, how would you solve this problem?

Comment: I'm also wondering about this. Some recommend an event bus, but to me that's just hiding the coupling between the systems and makes obscures code flow. Take it with a grain of salt, but N.2 sounds logical to me, you're using the same architecture/pattern to solve all your problems. Don't see anything wrong with 'persistent' vs 'transient' entities that just get cleaned up at end of frame. An entity is a collection of information that gets transported to different systems anyways.